# Geodesics and minimal surfaces.

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, riemannian-geometry

We say that a submanifold $M$ of a Riemannian manifold $(N,h)$ is minimal if it's second fundamental form is traceless i.e (as far as I understand)

Trace $B = \sum_{0}^{m}B(X_{i},X_{i})=0$,

for any orthonormal frame for the tangent bundle $TM$.

Is this in some sense multidimensional analogue of a geodesic? Minimal surfaces seams to be the minimize the area functional instead of length functional.

Comment: Of course you mean $\sum B(X_i,X_i)$. You're right that minimal $k$-dimensional submanifolds are critical points of the $k$-dimensional area functional. But I would say that totally geodesic submanifolds (if any exist) are the immediate generalization of geodesics.

Comment: @TedShifrin are the former more general then the latter?

Comment: It's truly comparing apples and oranges. They are different differential-geometric constructions entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed. The trick is to realize that geodesics in a Riemannian manifold $N$  are critical points (in a suitable sense, see below) for the energy functional on the space of maps ${\mathbb R}\to N$.  Now, to extend this interpretation in higher dimensions,  fix two Riemannian manifolds $M, N$ and consider the space of Riemannian isometric immersions $Imm(M,N)$. Since $M$ need not be compact one has to restrict energy variation to variations which are trivial away from compacts (i.e. are "compactly supported"). Then $f\in Imm(M,N)$ is minimal iff it is harmonic iff it is a critical point of energy functional under compactly supported variations. See

J.Eells and J.Sampson, [Harmonic mappings of Riemannian manifolds](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~js/Math646/eells-sampson.pdf), American Journal of Mathematics, Vol. 86, No. 1 (1964), pp. 109-160.

This is not the end of the story since harmonic and minimal maps (unlike nonconstant geodesics) need not be immersions, but I think, this suffices for your purposes.